# How to hide logger output in Jupyter notebook but still continue the backend logging

Tags: logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, loguru

Is there a way to hide the printed output inside Jupyter notebook (the red background section encircled in green) while still maintaining the info logging capabilities such as saving the logs into a .log file?

[image]

I saw threads talking about changing the LEVEL, but that is not what I am looking for since I want to keep the level at INFO to continue logging the INFO logs.

Comment: Am also open to answers that use the default `logging` library in Python, instead of loguru!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)" and
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Comment: Is something supposed to be circled in green?

Answer (score 1):

FYI the display in red in Jupyter is from the `sys.stderr` stream. What you are looking for is to perform logging that writes to file without writing to STDERR.

Following [docs for the logging standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook), you can set up a logger that writes to a FileHandler, as below:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('my_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler('my_log_file.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# Does not write to sys.stderr
logger.info("These logs do not show up on Jupyter!")
```